# Yii2 navbar active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

How can I set the navbar tickets/index item to active also when I am in tickets/view when there is no menu item for tickets/view? I tried this.

```
$menuItems[] = [
    'label' => 'Tickets',
    'url' => [
        '/tickets/index'
        'active' => in_array(\Yii::$app->controller->id,['tickets'])
    ] 
];
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply try :

```
$menuItems[] = [
    'label' => 'Tickets',
    'url' => ['/tickets/index'],
    'active' => in_array(\Yii::$app->controller->id, ['tickets']),
];
```

> `active`: boolean, optional, whether the item should be on active state or not.

Read more about [Nav items](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html#$items-detail).

Answer (score 0):

for single item  you can use the visible attribute

```
[
  'label' => '<Tickets',
  'url' => [''/tickets/index''],
  'visible' =>  in_array(\Yii::$app->controller->id,['tickets']),
],
```